# anagram string edit distance algorithm/code?

Tags: algorithm, anagram

There are two anagram strings S and P. There are two basic operations:

1. Swap two letters that are in neighborhood, e.g, swap "A" and "C" in BCCAB, cost is 1.
2. Swap the first letter and the last letter in the string, cost is 1.

Question: Design an efficient algorithm that minimize the cost to change S to P.

I tried a greedy algorithm, but I found counter examples and I think it is incorrect. I know famous DP problem edit distance, but I did not get the formula for this one.

Anyone can help? An idea and pseudo code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm would count as efficient? For a heuristic, look for the smallest distance each character has to go, treating the string as a circle, and divide the sum of these distances by two. On the circle, each character needs to participate in enough swaps to move it, one step at a time, to its destination, and each swap affects only two characters, so this heuristic should be a lower bound to the number of swaps required.

Answer (score 0):

Without the ends-swap the answer is simple: you have to get the first and last letter right, and there's no way to "save" by doing it later; hence for word a<sub>i</sub> where `0 <= i < n` you'd "bubble" the correct a<sub>0</sub> and a<sub>n-1</sub> in place, then repeat for the word a<sub>i</sub> where `1 <= i < n-1` until you're left with 0 or 1 letters.

With the ends-swap option, you're left with much harder problem, since there are two directions where each letter can arrive in the correct place. You'd basically have a bipartite graph between source and target word, and you'd want to find a matching that minimizes the sum of distances. Even that is not really an algorithm, since each swap moves two of the letters, not just one.

Bottom line is, you may have to do a search, but at least you can bound the search with the no-ends-swap distance.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to find a solution if you forget about the second rule and simply treat the string as a cyclic buffer where you can bubble 'around' in both directions - just a different mental model actually...